# Delete on cascade for oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, data-warehouse, database-administration

Is there any ways to perform delete on cascade without locking all the child tables.Also the delete is performed on the key which is not the foreign key in the child tables .The foreign key in the child tables is indexed.Currently the situation is that when the delete is happening the locks on all the child tables which does not allow inserts to occur because of the locks

thanks

sri

Comment: Delete on cascade does not require full table locks - please provide example table definitions with the details of constraints and indexes so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, you can add a field with two possible values "Y"/"N" ("1"/"0", etc) that will show that the record has been deleted already. Then you can build a job [(it is ok for long term operation)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/process.htm#BABDECGE) This process will be working in background, it will be collecting deleted rows and delete them.

Second way, try to run your transaction, and when you see your table got a full lock execute:

```
ALTER TABLE <<YOUR_LOCKED_TABLE_NAME>> DISABLE TABLE LOCKS
```

Then your transaction has to finish with the exception `ORA-00069`, if so, your table is really locked and you have to check if you have B-Tree indexes on your foreign key and you don't use any bitmap indexes.